# В триггере не устанавливается значение селекта

Tags: mysql, триггер

У меня есть несколько таблиц с одинаковым полем, значения которого не должны повторяться. Решил сделать генерацию этого значения при внесении записи. Триггер просто вытаскивает максимальное значение и прибавляет 1. Но почему-то  после `SELECT MAX(account_number) AS last_account_number INTO last_account_number FROM companies;` last_account_number всегда null, хотя значения там есть и сам по себе запрос отрабатывает нормально.

Сам триггер.

```
CREATE DEFINER=`root`@`localhost` TRIGGER    generate_account_number_for_companies
before insert
ON companies FOR EACH ROW

BEGIN
    DECLARE account_number INT;
    DECLARE last_account_number INT;

    SELECT MAX(account_number) AS last_account_number INTO last_account_number FROM companies;

    IF last_account_number is null THEN
            SET New.account_number = 10000000;
    ELSE
            SET New.account_number = last_account_number + 1;
    END IF;
END
```

Так же пробовал и через SET. Результат тот же.

```
DECLARE last_account_number INT;
SET last_account_number = (SELECT MAX(account_number) account_number FROM companies );
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Вы объявляете у себя в триггере переменную `DECLARE account_number INT;`. Ее имя совпадает с именем колонки в вашей таблице. И когда вы делаете `SELECT MAX(account_number) AS last_account_number INTO last_account_number FROM companies;` MySQL решает имя локальной переменной более приоритетным, чем имя колонки и выбирает значение из этой переменной, а значение для нее вы не задали.

Учитывая, что данная переменная вообще не используется в коде - просто уберите ее. И в дальнейшем избегайте называть переменные так же как колонки в таблицах с которыми работаете. Либо в select явно указывайте колонку с именем таблицы: `SELECT MAX(companies.account_number) INTO last_account_number FROM companies;`